# What is the Kubuntu equivalent for 'Network tools' as in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, kubuntu

There is a tool in ubuntu system -> administration -> Network Tools.

What is the KDE equivalent for this?

Comment: I have never seen such a tool in KDE, the only "network tool" that is not a configuration application is "Networkinterfaces".

Answer (score 1):

- I think it's **net-tools** in kubuntu.
- If you want to install the gnome version it's called **gnome-nettool** in the repositories..
- Also see this **[link](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-network/screenshots.shtml)**.

Comment: I think (s)he wanted a kde version ;)